# Fix virtualenv after installing python 3 with brew

Tags: homebrew, python

Previously I had the default Python 2.7, and I have a lot of virtualenvs created under python 2, using virtualenvwrapper. Recently, I wanted to be able to use python 3 as well as python 2.

`brew install python3` no longer works, so after some research, I ran `brew upgrade python` followed by `brew install python2` to get back Python 2. However, I discovered that the python 3 installation process changed the default "python" to python 3, and that this broke all of my virtualenvs.

For example, if I execute `workon test` in the console, I get the errors

> /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module
>   specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader'
>   (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
>   /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module
>   specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader'
>   (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
>   /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module
>   specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader'
>   (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
>   /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6: Error while finding module
>   specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader'
>   (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')

How can I unscrew-up my system? I need to be able to get back all my old work, even if it means obliterating python 3, although the ideal solution would be to find a way to have python 3 installed along side without interfering with the existing python 2 setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually solved the issue by running

```
brew switch python 2.7.14
brew link --overwrite python
```

I'm not sure if that was the correct solution, but at least it seems to be working now.

Comment: confirmed. i didn't even need `brew link`; `brew switch` alone fixed it for me.

Comment: That gives me an error: `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:12:in require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:12:in <top (required)>'
 from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in require_relative'
 from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in <main>' `